# JavaScript querySelectorAll elements order

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need help with getting elements by `querySelectorAll` function.
When I call it and I pass a string as parameter of this function with multiple elements separated with commas, it will `return` me a `NodeList` with nodes but, they are sort by `first-depth traversal pre-order` (which should be as they are positioned in `document body`). And I have a problem when I want to call a `method` to return values of more elements in `document` saved in `Array`. So I call this

```
$('#textinput, #someotherinput').value();
```

where element with `id #someotherinput` is positioned above the element `#textinput`, but the result after `querySelectorAll` is this:

```
[input#someotherinput, input#textinput]
   0: input#someotherinput
   1: input#textinput
   length: 2
   __proto__: NodeList
```

and I need to sort them way I did when I called `$()`, because when I need to use values, I look just at `$('#textinput, #someotherinput')` and it's annoying to find out an order of the elements in `document body` and use returned array with values of those elements when I don't know what is saved in first (0th) position in array. And yes, I know that `querySelectorAll` is `traversal pre-order` function. So, how to sort (easy as possible) elements to MY order?

Comment: What if multiple elements are found by one of the selectors, or an element is found by multiple selectors? How would those be sorted?

Comment: If one element is found by multiple selectors, the order does not matter. I think it would be sorted by way as attributes sorted are. So `<input type="text" id="idselector" class="classSelector" />`  and I call `$('.classSelector, #idselector')`  the result of `querySelectorAll` is nodeList with `input#idselector` on 0th position

Comment: The nodes are returned in document order. The algorithm is to descend the document tree, testing each node against the selector(s). If the node matches any of them, it is added to the list. The selector is effectively "*select elements with an ID of textinput or someotherinput*", so the order of the selectors does not affect the order of the returned nodes. Oh, and a NodeList is not an Array.

Comment: I've got it. And I know that NodeList is not an Array. I meant when I call method value() with no arguments passed, the returning value is an array of values of those selectors.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to determine if an element would be matched by a selector. You would have to reimplement the entire rule matching system, so the easiest way is to simply use the selector to query for the elements.

The simplest way to get the elements in the order that you like, would be to split the selector into its subselectors, do a query for each, then put the results together by eliminating duplicate element references.